# How can I make a package importable before any other package gets loaded in Sublime Text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to create a Sublime Text package named "Common" which contains some common functions that can be used by all other packages.

Its file structure is like:

```
Common
 common.py
```

Then I create a package named "A" to use functions defined in Common/common.py

```
A
 a.py
```

In a.py, I try to import common.py

```
import common
```

Because Sublime Text loads packages in alphabetic order I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 62, in reload_plugin
  File ".\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import common
ImportError: No module named common
```

How can I make a package importable before any other package gets loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. you already included the answer in your question. If Sublime Text loads Packages in alphabethic order, you should give your package a name that puts it before all other packages.

I guess that also explains the package name "AAAPackageDev"